# I always send texts to my email for important information I need. I just realized they are not going to email. And no longer visible in text sents

Tags: iphone, email, text, yahoo

So my sent texts have been deleted in my phone, although older messages remain. I have been sending texts samples to my yahoo email. It shows delivered but I can’t find them anywhere. I need those texts I sent. They were sent May 12,23. Anyway to retrieve them?

Comment: This is confusing.  You say “texts have been deleted from your phone”, but then you say “it shows delivered.” They can’t show as delivered and simultaneously not exist.   Are they deleted from Messages or from Mail or both?  When you say “you can’t find them anywhere”, what exactly does this mean?  Where did you look?  Also, which iPhone, what version of iOS, which carrier?

Comment: Yes, can you clarify and provide more information? What iPhone? What iOS version? When you say "texts", are you talking about Messages.app or Mail.app (or something else, like Whatsapp)? Did you delete these messages? How exactly did you send texts to your email?